# Add field date to node tpl

Tags: theming, entities

I'm using a template that has this on the portfolio.tpl:

[image]

But I don't want to display the date of node created.
So, I added in the content type portfolio a field "date_field" (please see picture)[image]

What I need now is to display **this field** on the tpl, replacing the "$node->created".

This is what I tried:

[image]

But it doesn't work.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php print format_date($node->field_date["und"][0]["value"], 'custom','d M Y'); ?>
```

Comment: It returns this: Warning: date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date()

Comment: Just do a print of the date to see what value you have: print  render ( $node->field_date["und"][0]["value"] ) ; It seems to me that it is a matter of the format. I have tested the code above and works perfectly. But the value was in seconds, if you already have in date format, you are done with the line I copied before. As for print render $content["field_date"], it won't work.

Comment: You don't need to wrap format_date() in a render().
And it is preferable to use [LANGUAGE_NONE] instead of ["und"].

Comment: You can use dpm, Devel module or just do echo "<pre>";print_r($node);echo "</pre>" to see all variables available to .tpl.php. Don't be afraid if you see thousands and thousands of lines, for a single page Drupal loads tonns of data and metadata and loads memory as if it were a WBH ( Web-Black-Hole ).

Comment: dmsmidt, it depends on the source of your data. If the value is already a date in legible (human readable format), you are right, otherwise you will use format_date. Here the problem is that $content['field_date'] is not available to *.tpl.php, but node->field_date[][][] is.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the strtotime:
<?php print render(format_date(strtotime($node->field_date["und"][0]["value"])), 'custom','d M Y'); ?>
and it works!
Only problem is that ii appears with the hour: Tue, 09/01/2015 - 00:00. Any thoughts on deleting the hour?

Comment: @Cesar format_date() returns a string so you don't need the render(). It is correct that if the value of the field is not a UNIX timestamp, you have to convert it to one before using. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7

Comment: You can set a date format here: #overlay=es/admin/config/regional/date-time. Then you change the code to:        $date_arr = explode("T" , $node->field_date["und"][0]["value"]);
    print     format_date ( strtotime($date_arr[0]), "friendly")      ; where "friendly" is the name of the custom hour format. And yes, you are right about render. Also, notice that ["und"] should be changed to more appropriate LANGUAGE_NONE   .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the field is visible under 'Manage Display' for the view mode you are working with.

If you setup the field to display in a format you like you can also just do this in your template file (instead of the format_date() part):

```
<?php print render($content['field_date'] ?>
```

In any case make sure that you also do the following before $content is rendered:

```
<?php print hide($content['field_date']) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I really want is to display in that specific format date.

Comment: Sidenote: You can add a custom date format in Drupal, which you then can reuse across your site.