# Add field date to views tpl

Tags: views, theming

I had this issue before which I solved:
[Add field date to node tpl](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192720/add-field-date-to-node-tpl/192721?noredirect=1#comment232707_192721)

Now I need to add the date field in the views.tpl.php

Here's the code:

[image]

I want to replace "$date->node_created" with the field_date.

Here's what I know: I can't use $content['field_date'] because the $content array doesn't exist in this template file.

Thank you

Comment: Logic like this should be done in a preprocess function not your tpl. Then you can simply add it to your $vars and render it in your tpl.

Comment: After reading this a second time I am wondering what exactly you are trying to do. It seems to me there should be a much better way to handle what I am seeing. Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know what fields you have available to your View, you can use a custom module, and there you write the following:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
     if($view->name == "YOUR_VIEW_NAME"){
         foreach($view->result as $key => $r){
             echo "<pre>"; print_r($view->result[$key]); echo "</pre>";
     ....
         } // foreach
      } // if view->name
} // function
```

Comment: This is what I found: http://i.imgur.com/6Jk6aJq.jpg I tried "$date->field_date["und"][0]["value"]" but it says: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_date in include()

Comment: Try with `$data["field_date"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"]`

Comment: By the way, you are re-writing $date in line 10. That is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't work. I managed to display the field as you can see here http://i.imgur.com/8A2vzrs.jpg but it appears "node" and not the date...
(btw, I changed the field_date to field_dateofevent) where can I change this value?

Comment: I am not sure of what you pretend to do. You are mixing concepts and you must definitely know if you want to use or modify your data in the *.tpl, in the module or where, and know what data you have available at each moment. If you are using a view but do not include the field in that view, it will not render.

Comment: I recommend that you inspect your View in the View UI, you include the field_dateofevent and later you can try to access the value in the views.tpl.php, but first you must include it and be sure that it is there. In the module, you can use this piece of code to know if it is present: function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
 if($view->name == "YOUR_VIEW_NAME"){
  foreach($view->result as $key => $r){
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($view->result[$key]); echo "</pre>"; // with this line, you see the structure of the fields and see if yours is present.
  } // foreach
 } // if
} // function

Comment: I did it with: $date->field_field_dateofevent[0]["raw"]["value"]
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to accomodate to your attempts. If my answer was helpful to you for solving the issue, please mark my answer as Correct so I get some extra points! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Done! It sure was helpfull :)